laravel datatable takes long time to load with only two records
i have the following code with only 2 records of data
my controller :
        if (request()->ajax()){
        $spareparts = Sparepart::select(DB::raw('DATE_FORMAT(spareparts.created_at,"%d-%m-%Y") as order_date'),
        DB::raw("CONCAT(users.address, ', ', regencies.name, ', ', districts.name, ', ', provinces.name) as address"),
        DB::raw("CONCAT(shipping_addresses.full_address, ', ', r.name, ', ', d.name, ', ', p.name) as shipping_address"),
        DB::raw("GROUP_CONCAT(distinct sp.nama order by sp.id SEPARATOR ', ') as nama_sparepart"),
        DB::raw("GROUP_CONCAT(distinct sp.model order by sp.id SEPARATOR ', ') as model"),
        DB::raw("GROUP_CONCAT(distinct kategori_produks.nama SEPARATOR ', ') as nama"),
        DB::raw("GROUP_CONCAT(distinct sp.quantity order by sp.id SEPARATOR ', ') as quantity"),
        DB::raw("GROUP_CONCAT(distinct sp.foto SEPARATOR ', ') as foto"),
        'spareparts.id', 'users.name', 'users.no_hp')
        ->leftJoin('sparepart_products as sp', 'spareparts.id', '=', 'sp.sparepart_id')
        ->leftJoin('users', 'spareparts.email', '=', 'users.email')
        ->leftJoin('shipping_addresses', 'users.email', '=', 'shipping_addresses.email')
        ->leftJoin('kategori_produks', 'sp.kategori_id', '=', 'kategori_produks.id')
        ->leftJoin('provinces', 'users.provinsi', '=', 'provinces.id')
        ->leftJoin('regencies', 'users.kota', '=', 'regencies.id')
        ->leftJoin('districts', 'users.kecamatan', '=', 'districts.id')
        ->leftJoin('provinces as p', 'shipping_addresses.provinsi', '=', 'p.id')
        ->leftJoin('regencies as r', 'shipping_addresses.kota', '=', 'r.id')
        ->leftJoin('districts as d', 'shipping_addresses.kecamatan', '=', 'd.id')
        ->where('spareparts.is_deleted', 0)
        ->groupBy('spareparts.id', 'shipping_addresses.full_address','r.name', 'd.name', 'p.name', 
        'regencies.name', 'districts.name', 'provinces.name')
        ->distinct();

        if($request->filled('from_date') && $request->filled('to_date')) {
            $spareparts = $spareparts->whereDate('spareparts.created_at', '>=', $request->from_date)->whereDate('spareparts.created_at', '<=', $request->to_date);
        }
        if(!empty($request->install_by)) {
            $spareparts = $spareparts->where('kategori_produks.nama', $request->install_by);
        }

        return DataTables::of($spareparts)->addColumn('action', function ($id) {
            if(Auth::user()->role == 'admin'){
                return '<a href="sparepart-request/edit/' . $id->id . '" class="btn btn-primary">Edit</a>
                        <a href="sparepart-request/' . $id->id . '/delete" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</a>';
            }
            else{
                return '<a href="sparepart-request/edit/' . $id->id . '" class="btn btn-primary">Edit</a>';
            }
        })->make();
    }

my view :
                        <table id="tbl_sparepart" class="table table-striped table-bordered nowrap" cellspacing="0"
                        width="100%">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Order Date</th>
                                <th>Name</th>
                                <th>Phone Number</th>
                                <th>Address</th>
                                <th>Shipping Address</th>
                                {{-- <th>Sparepart Name</th>
                                <th>Quantity</th>
                                <th>Category</th>
                                <th>Model</th>
                                <th>Sparepart Foto</th> --}}
                                <th>Action</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>

                        </tbody>
                    </table>
        var table_service = $('#tbl_sparepart').DataTable({
        processing: true,
        serverSide: true,
        layout: {
            topStart: {
                'pageLength': 10,
                buttons: [{
                    extend: 'csv',
                    text: 'Export Data',
                    filename: 'sparepart'
                }]
            }
        },
        scrollX: true,
        ajax: {
            url: '/sparepart-request',
            data: function(d) {
                d.from_date = $('input[name="daterange"]').data('daterangepicker').startDate
                    .format('YYYY-MM-DD');
                d.to_date = $('input[name="daterange"]').data('daterangepicker').endDate.format(
                    'YYYY-MM-DD');
                d.category_type = $('#category_type').val();
            }
        },
        columns: [{
                data: 'order_date',
                name: 'order_date',
                searchable: false
            },
            {
                data: 'name',
                name: 'users.name'
            },
            {
                data: 'no_hp',
                name: 'users.no_hp'
            },
            {
                data: 'address',
                name: 'users.address'
            },
            {
                data: 'shipping_address',
                name: 'shipping_address',
                searchable: false
            },
            {
                data: 'nama_sparepart',
                name: 'sp.nama'
            },
            {
                data: 'quantity',
                name: 'sp.quantity'
            },
            {
                data: 'nama',
                name: 'kategori_produks.nama'
            },
            {
                data: 'model',
                name: 'sp.model'
            },
            {
                data: 'foto',
                name: 'sp.foto'
            },
            {
                data: 'action',
                name: 'action',
                orderable: false,
                searchable: false
            },
        ]
    });

and somehow it takes 10-30 seconds to load 2 records of data, but when i remove group_concat from my query, it makes the load time faster but i cant remove group_concat since i need it in my query.
i will appreciate any help, thanks in advance.

Seems more like a case for SQL optimization than PHP and Laravel code. A couple tips: make sure that the columns used in your WHERE clauses, JOINs, and ORDER BY are properly indexed in the database. Use Laravel Debugbar or print the generated query and inspect it using EXPLAIN. Once you confirm that your query is good, then come back to PHP.

It's not the number of rows returned that's an issue, it's the number of rows that have to be processed. You've got 10 joins, 8 group-bys, and 4 where clauses. Certainly at least one of those isn't indexed. shipping_addresses.email seems like a likely candidate.

There are so many things wrong here. Anyway, here's an optimized version.
if (request()->ajax()) {
$spareparts = Sparepart::select([
        DB::raw('DATE_FORMAT(spareparts.created_at,"%d-%m-%Y") as order_date'),
        DB::raw("CONCAT(users.address, ', ', regencies.name, ', ', districts.name, ', ', provinces.name) as address"),
        DB::raw("CONCAT(shipping_addresses.full_address, ', ', r.name, ', ', d.name, ', ', p.name) as shipping_address"),
        DB::raw("GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT sp.nama ORDER BY sp.id SEPARATOR ', ') as nama_sparepart"),
        DB::raw("GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT sp.model ORDER BY sp.id SEPARATOR ', ') as model"),
        DB::raw("GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT kategori_produks.nama SEPARATOR ', ') as nama"),
        DB::raw("GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT sp.quantity ORDER BY sp.id SEPARATOR ', ') as quantity"),
        DB::raw("GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT sp.foto SEPARATOR ', ') as foto"),
        'spareparts.id', 'users.name', 'users.no_hp'
    ])
    ->leftJoin('sparepart_products as sp', 'spareparts.id', '=', 'sp.sparepart_id')
    ->leftJoin('users', 'spareparts.email', '=', 'users.email')
    ->leftJoin('shipping_addresses', 'users.email', '=', 'shipping_addresses.email')
    ->leftJoin('kategori_produks', 'sp.kategori_id', '=', 'kategori_produks.id')
    ->leftJoin('provinces', 'users.provinsi', '=', 'provinces.id')
    ->leftJoin('regencies', 'users.kota', '=', 'regencies.id')
    ->leftJoin('districts', 'users.kecamatan', '=', 'districts.id')
    ->leftJoin('provinces as p', 'shipping_addresses.provinsi', '=', 'p.id')
    ->leftJoin('regencies as r', 'shipping_addresses.kota', '=', 'r.id')
    ->leftJoin('districts as d', 'shipping_addresses.kecamatan', '=', 'd.id')
    ->where('spareparts.is_deleted', 0)
    ->groupBy([
        'spareparts.id', 'shipping_addresses.full_address', 'r.name', 'd.name', 'p.name',
        'regencies.name', 'districts.name', 'provinces.name'
    ]);

// Apply date range filter if provided
if ($request->filled('from_date') && $request->filled('to_date')) {
    $spareparts->whereBetween('spareparts.created_at', [
        $request->from_date, $request->to_date
    ]);
}

// Filter by install_by if provided
if ($request->filled('install_by')) {
    $spareparts->where('kategori_produks.nama', $request->install_by);
}

// Return DataTables with action column
return DataTables::of($spareparts)
    ->addColumn('action', function ($row) {
        $buttons = '<a href="sparepart-request/edit/' . $row->id . '" class="btn btn-primary">Edit</a>';
        if (Auth::user()->role == 'admin') {
            $buttons .= '<a href="sparepart-request/' . $row->id . '/delete" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</a>';
        }
        return $buttons;
    })
    ->make(true);

}
Things to consider to make it better.

Simplify Joins: Ensure that your joins are essential and properly indexed in the database. For instance, combining data from users and shipping_addresses could be revisited to see if they can be fetched separately and merged at the application level.
Avoid GROUP_CONCAT Abuse: GROUP_CONCAT may cause performance issues for large datasets. If possible, normalize this data at the database or use Laravel's hasMany relationships for nested data.
Use Select Scopes: Create query scopes for repeated patterns like filtering dates or joining specific tables.
Optimize Grouping and Aggregations: Group and aggregate only what is necessary to minimize computation.
Index Frequent Columns: Ensure columns used in WHERE, GROUP BY, and JOIN are indexed
And of course, caching


If the GROUP_CONCATs are definitely the culprit then you could consider having a dedicated index table which pre-builds all the concatenated strings into columns.
The index table would be a copy of the data from the other tables in your query above, but would already have the data formatted as required. You would have a script which can build this table at any time (could run every hour, for example to re-build).
You can then query this index table instead from the frontend for much faster querying.

Try to minimize the use of DISTINCT within GROUP_CONCAT. You can achieve this by grouping your posts more efficiently. Use with() to eagerly load instead of manual connections. This reduces the number of queries and speeds up the process.
